# Receive full row in distinct query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have a table with let's say 3 Fields in a mdb-database:

ID | API-Key | Name

This table can contain multiple datasets where the API-Key can be identical.

Now I need to get only datasets with distinct API-Keys.

So For example with the following datasets:

```
1 | abc | Test1
2 | def | Test2
3 | abc | Test3
4 | xyz | Test4
5 | xyz | Test5
6 | abc | Test6
```

I need to get something like:

```
1 | abc | Test1
2 | def | Test2
4 | xyz | Test4
```

It doesn't matter which of the datasets with identical API-Key is returned.

I already searched google for about 30 min. but doesn't found anything matching my needs.
Also tried around a bit but didn't found any working solution.

I hope someone has an idea.

Comment: What I understand is you are looking to display unique result set ?

Comment: Re "I already searched google for about 30 min" - can't you think of algorithm, giving you required results and then implement that? Searching google is not efficient for finding full solutions. Hint: find correct set of ID's in inner query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't care, the database engine needs to know which records/values to select. So you need some aggregate function, e.g. `MIN()`

DISTINCT would only help if you just want to retrieve the API keys, if you want full records you need grouping.

```
SELECT Min(ID) AS SomeID, API_Key, Min(Name) AS SomeName
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY API_Key
```